# How convert an image in a code understood by browsers

Tags: html, image, embed

I would like to convert an entire image into it hex code for example and them embed it into an html document for display.

I know it can be done with vectors (svg for example), the problem is that they don't look that good for a photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about base64?

you can use online convertor, like http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter

Comment: Is there any other way? just curious